# Q: Can't install PyQt4 on osx

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pyqt4

I've tried to install pyqt4 on osx using the following guide: http://www.noktec.be/python/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-osx

Everything works fine up until installing sip; when I import sip in pycharm right now I get no error messages.

However, when I enter in my terminal:

```
cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4
```

or

```
cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4
```

or

```
cd /Users/username/Downloads/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4
```

I get a message saying:

```
-bash: cd: PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why, since I used exactly the same terminal commands when I installed sip, and the sip and python files are both in the same download map.

If it wasn't obvious by now; I'm a complete beginner regarding mac directories, paths and file/folder locations so it would be really nice if someone could link a tutorial/guide me in the right direction. I do want to use pyqt4 in the near future though, so help regarding the installation of pyqt4 would really be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Update: Right now I'm able to do:

```
cd /Users/username/Downloads/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4\ 6
```

However, when I enter the next step:

```
python configure.py -q /usr/bin/qmake-4.8 -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/ --use-arch x86_64
```

I get a message saying '/usr/bin/qmake-4.8' is not a file. Which file extension should I use here instead?

If I use '/usr/bin/local/' instead I get a message saying:

```
can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Second Update:

When I enter in my terminal:

```
python /Users/username/Downloads/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4\ 6/configure.py
```

It seems to work, until I get an error message saying:

```
Error: unable to create the C++ code.
```

Comment: if you manual go to the downloads directory,do you see the folder `PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4` ??

Comment: Do you mean if I click on downloads through Finder? If so; yes!

Comment: try to `cd` the downloads folder first then use `ls` to list everything it has then `cd` the exactly file you need.